# Why does it show 0 on click and not 1? (javascript html)

Tags: javascript, function, increment

I have built a small website, where I have a html button and an html input text field.
I wanted to create a js function which manipulates the value of the input field by incrementing it by 1.

my html :

```
<button onclick="increment()">Click to + 1!</button>
<input id="inc" type="text"/>
```

my javascript:

```
var i = 0;
function increment() {
var textbox = document.
getElementById("inc");
textbox.value = i;
i++;

}
```

I wonder why the first time you press on the button it displays 0.

I defined i as 0. but in the function the last statement is : i++;

Therefore shouldnt it display 1 ? (0+1)

I am confused about how the function is executed line by line.

Hope you can help me understand it :)

Comment: But you set `textbox.value` before incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting `textbox.value = i;` before you increment `i`, and before the first time `i` is incremented, `i` is 0. To fix this, just move the statement that increments `i` before you set the value of the input. Like this:

```js
const textbox = document.getElementById("inc");

let i = 0;
function increment() {
  i++;
  textbox.value = i;
}

document.getElementById('inc_btn').addEventListener('click', increment);
```

```html
<button id="inc_btn">Click to + 1!</button>
<input id="inc" type="text" />
```

In the code above I also changed your `onclick` attribute into an event listener, which is the recommended practice in modern times. It is also better to make `textbox` a global variable, or else the browser will have to fetch it every time, rather than once.